# Gravity Forms eWAY / add extra card number validation via jQuery or PHP

Tags: wordpress, validation, credit-card, gravityforms

I have a Wordpress gravity form with the eWAY credit card field. I would like to specify certain numbers for the first four credit card digits and stop them to be used during the validation, even if the full number is a valid credit card number.

I believe this is the logic I'm looking to implement: **if the first 4 digits of the credit card number are 4001, 4002 and 4003, display the validation error message.**

I hope that makes sense.

Regards,

Comment: code ? what have you tried ?

Comment: It is a client requirement and I don't know why.
The form is this one: https://lateralevents.com/signature-events/vip-meet-greet-whats-next/

Is it possible to add the logic mentioned in my post to the 
Card Number field? Basically, to block specific first 4 digits displaying an error message.